# Catchable fatal error: Object could not be converted to string - but var_dump says it IS a string

Tags: php

I have a problem that was already asked by a lot of people here: when trying to echo a string, "Catchable fatal error: Object of class Struct could not be converted to string in D:\Programy\XAMP\htdocs\e-history\test.php on line 30". For most related questions, trying `var_dump()` function was suggested. However, I tried this and everything seems to be OK, except for it throws the error.

My code (testing version):

```
$place = Struct::factory('gid','lat','lon','radius');

$places = loadPlaces('', 50, 14);
$j = 0;

var_dump($places[$j]->gid);
echo "$places[$j]->gid";
```

The output of var_dump and echo is as follows:

```
string(1) "6"
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Struct could not be converted to string in D:\Programy\XAMP\htdocs\e-history\test.php on line 30
```

Usually there are no problems with $object->value notation, and I don't know why it doesn't work in this case. I had some problems with array/object mismatches, but I'm almost sure it's not this case. Any idea how to solve it?

EDIT: line 30 in my code is: `echo "$places[$j]->gid";`

Comment: please specify what line 30 in your script contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between those two lines:

```
echo "$places[$j]->gid";
echo $places[$j]->gid;
```

The first one incorrectly tries to access an object inside a string variable. The second one accesses it just like `var_dump`. There is no need to wrap variables inside double quotes!

The first version should be like this:

```
echo "{$places[$j]->gid}";
```

Comment: Works. I'll accept your answer after 8 minutes - you're fast, it's too early now :-)